# Clearing worn equipment in minecraft via command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to remove all worn equipment (in addition to inventory) of a player when they enter a certain area. /clear removes inventory items correctly, but not worn equipment. I am wondering if it is a plugin issue with Essentials? Is there a way to clear worn equipment with command blocks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/clear` works fine for me. Try using the vanilla command rather than the one from Essentials, if possible, you do this by using `/minecraft:clear`.

Alternatively, you could try using `/replaceitem` with air, like this:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.feet air
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.legs air
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head air
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.chest air
```